# Expanding a recursive macro in rust, similar to serde_json but for HTML elements

Tags: rust, rust-macros

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! reactant {
    // Converts (function) {...} into element
    ( $f:ident $t:tt ) => {
        {
            let mut elem = HtmlElement::new($f);
            reactant!(@expand elem $t);
            elem
        }
    };

    // Expands {...} and parses each internal node individually
    ( @expand $self:ident { $($t:tt),* } ) => {
        $(
            reactant!(@generate $self $t);
        )*
    };

    // Takes a (function) {...} node, feeds it back recursively, and pushes it into parent
    ( @generate $self:ident $t1:tt $t2:tt) => {
        {
            $self.push_inner(reactant!($t1 $t2));
        }
    };

    // Takes a literal and sets the parent internal to a string
    ( @generate $self:ident $l:literal) => {
        {
            $self.set_inner(String::from($l)).unwrap();
        }
    };

}

#[allow(unused_macros)]
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use crate::html::types::*;
    use crate::html::HtmlElement;
    use crate::reactant;

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        // Doesn't work, not expecting '{' after second div, although the first one works fine
        let x = reactant!(div {
            div {
                "test"
            }
        });

        // Works, outputs <div>thing</div>
        let y = reactant!(div {
            "hello",
            "thing"
        });

    }
}
```

I am working on making an uncreatively named HTML library in Rust, and am also learning macros at the same time (the macro documentation is confusing). Part of the project is making a macro that generates HTML elements recursively to make a document, in a similar appearance to serde_json. The syntax is shown in the test cases. Basically, every HTML element (div, h1, etc.) is mapped to a function that outputs a struct that I have crafted for HTML elements. I managed to get the macro working in one way, but it only allowed for HTML children when I want it to also take literals to fill in, say, an h1 with a string (test case 1). Test case 2 shows where it doesn't work, and I am not understanding why it can't read the {.

Comment: "_the macro documentation is confusing_" → have you looked at [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://veykril.github.io/tlborm/)?

Comment: [Minimal reproducible example on playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=46e7c02108020ba00bcefd7150b72501)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to trace what happens when the macro is being expanded:

```
reactant!(div { div { "test" } });
```

This triggers the first rule: `$f:ident $t:tt` with:

- `$f` set to `div`
- `$t` set to `{ div { "test" } }`

Which gets expanded to:

```
reactant!(@expand elem { div { "test" } });
```

---

I believe you intended the second step to trigger rule number 2: `@expand $self:ident { $($t:tt),* }` with:

- `$self` set to `elem`
- `$t` set to `div { "test" }`

Which would get expanded to:

```
reactant!(@generate elem div { "test" });
```

**But** `div { "test" }` is actually **two** `tt`s and so can't be parsed by this rule (or by any other rule).

---

If my interpretation of your intentions is correct, you will need to have separate rules to handle each case and process the list iteratively:

```
    // Expands {...} and parses each internal node individually
    ( @expand $self:ident { $t1:tt $t2:tt, $($tail:tt)* } ) => {
            reactant!(@generate $self $t1 $t2);
            reactant!(@expand $self { $($tail)* })
    };
    ( @expand $self:ident { $t:tt, $($tail:tt)* } ) => {
            reactant!(@generate $self $t);
            reactant!(@expand $self { $($tail)* });
    };
    // Duplicate rules to handle the last item if it's not followed by a ","
    ( @expand $self:ident { $t1:tt $t2:tt } ) => {
            reactant!(@generate $self $t1 $t2);
    };
    ( @expand $self:ident { $t:tt } ) => {
            reactant!(@generate $self $t);
    };
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=df327c2831ee8f8c33ab7db2d9b95904)